# Recycle an inflated layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-inflate

I have to add multiple view programatically to a `HorizontalScrollView` but i can not add the same inflated view twice. So i have to re-inflate my `XML` layout N times. An adapter solution is not an option.

There is a way to recycle this layout without re-inflating?

Thanks to all.

**UPDATE**: My code is something like this.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, null);
HorizontalScrollView h = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);

for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
  // Process textview and images inside the view
  h.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: Is there any code in this application of yours? How are you inflating your layout?

Comment: Basically something like that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this what you are looking for we can inflate layout like this

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.abc_action_bar_decor, parent, true);
HorizontalScrollView h = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
LinearLayout parent= new LinearLayout(context);
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
h.addView(parent);
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_view, parent, true);
   // Process textview and images inside the view
}
```

Comment: This is what i want avoid: use the inflate function n times, i want to inflate my layout once and re use it in the for loop

Comment: @OllieStrevel This won't work, for each displayable list item you need a different View object, thus you need to inflate your layout for each item.